# How render a string as HTML in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm calling an API in ReactJS using axios. The call is successful but the output looks like the following:

```
Bitcoin has inspired other alternative currencies such as 
<a href="https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/litecoin">Litecoin</a>, 
<a href="https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/peercoin">Peercoin</a>
```

How can I render it as *HTML* and not as a *string* ?. Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class API extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            data: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin?localization=false')
            .then(res => {
                const data = res.data;
                console.log(res.data);
                this.setState({ data, loading: false })
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
           <div>
            {this.state.loading ? <p>Loading..</p> : 
              <p>{this.state.data.description.en}</p>
            }
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default API;
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini: OP has posted the code what is tried so far?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty there is no method that try to parse the response. So the OP has not tried to solve it

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini: lol, that is the question here!

Comment: There is no attempt in the code to solve the issue of removing `<a />` and render the result.

Comment: I had no ideas as to how I would go about solving the problem and was completely stuck... hence I decided to ask a question here.

Comment: @ShaneOG97 you need the anchor (link) on your Litecoin, Peercoin ?

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini: The code OP posted here is more than enough to be qualify to raise as a question in SO

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I misunderstood the requirement, as *replace the a href tags that are rendered with just "Litecoin" and "Peercoin"*, in my glossary means *remove a href tag before render*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)

```
 render() {
        return (
           <div>
            {this.state.loading ? <p>Loading..</p> : 
              <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:this.state.data.description.en}}></div>
            }
          </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: OP asked: 'How can I replace the a href tags that are rendered with just "Litecoin" and "Peercoin".'

Comment: of course, when you render the `<a href="https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/litecoin">Litecoin</a>` as html it becomes Litecoin. You can post an answer or leave it to the OP to comment on it

Comment: Ok, maybe the OP refers to the rendered HTML, instead of raw output

Comment: This solution answers the problem perfectly. Thanks humpty dumpty :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), but as the name suggests, it's dangerous.
See the snippet for demo code.

```js
const root = document.getElementById("root");
const App = () => {
  const APIData = `Bitcoin has inspired other alternative currencies such as 
<a href="https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/litecoin">Litecoin</a>, 
<a href="https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/peercoin">Peercoin</a>`;

  return (
    <div>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: APIData }} />
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></root>
```

Comment: OP asked: 'How can I replace the a href tags that are rendered with just "Litecoin" and "Peercoin".'

Comment: I misunderstood the requirement, as *replace the a href tags that are rendered with just "Litecoin" and "Peercoin"*, in my glossary means *remove a href tag before render*. You can well form a question and set it with wrong tags too.